# Pyspark display/show/collect showing invalid data

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm trying to filter a pyspark.sql.DataFrame and show the results. I have reason to believe the filters are working, but the display/show/collect commands display data, which violates the filters.

On databricks on azure I have a loaded a delta table as a pyspark.sql.DataFrame containing over 40 columns and 7 million rows. I've initialized a column with different datetime values for testing a new partitioning/versioning strategy.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

timestamps = [datetime.now() - timedelta(days=random.randint(0, 1000)) for i in range(0, 20)]
def create_random_datetime(col):
  return random.choice(timestamps)
dtf = F.udf(create_random_datetime, TimestampType())
df = df.withColumn('load_date', dtf(F.col('load_date')))
```

Also for the partitioning im extracting the year and month from the timestamp as new Integer-type columns.

```
df = df.withColumn('load_month', F.month(F.col('load_date')))
df = df.withColumn('load_year', F.year(F.col('load_date')))
```

Now I want to filter to the last 11 timestamps:

```
cutoff_datetime = df.select('load_date').distinct().orderBy('load_date', ascending=False).collect()[11][0]
cutoff_datetime # datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 25, 6, 37, 27, 261903)

df.select('load_date').filter(F.col('load_date') > cutoff_datetime).distinct().collect()
```

This shows a list of rows containing dates from 2021:

```
[Row(load_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 29, 6, 37, 27, 261897)),
...
 Row(load_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 15, 6, 37, 27, 261889)),
...
 Row(load_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 28, 6, 37, 27, 261920))]
```

I had the instinct I might be making a mistake handling the Timestamp data type. So I tried filtering the Integer columns `load_year` and `load_month`.

```
df_filtered =  df.filter('load_year > 2022')

df_filtered.select('load_year', 'load_month', 'load_date').limit(200).collect()
```

Still shows rows from 2021:

```
[Row(load_year=2022, load_month=11, load_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 1, 6, 37, 27, 261895)),
 Row(load_year=2021, load_month=12, load_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 6, 37, 27, 261924)),
 Row(load_year=2021, load_month=2, load_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 5, 6, 37, 27, 261911)),
...
 Row(load_year=2023, load_month=6, load_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 6, 6, 37, 27, 261868))]
```

Different variations in syntax (using `F.col` or not defining the filter criterion not as string literal) lead to the same results. Using the show, display or collect methods display the same unexpected dates.

My impression is that the filter step is working correctly:
`df.filter('load_year > 2023')` returns an empty DataFrame.

The command

```
print(f"{df.select('load_year').filter(df.load_year > 2022).count()=:,}, {df.select('load_year').count()=:,}")
print(f"{df.select('load_year').filter(df.load_year > 2021).count()=:,}, {df.select('load_year').count()=:,}")
print(f"{df.select('load_year').filter(df.load_year > 2020).count()=:,}, {df.select('load_year').count()=:,}")
```

prints

```
df.select('load_year').filter(df.load_year > 2022).count()=729,915, df.select('load_year').count()=7,296,062
df.select('load_year').filter(df.load_year > 2021).count()=4,378,659, df.select('load_year').count()=7,296,062
df.select('load_year').filter(df.load_year > 2020).count()=7,296,062, df.select('load_year').count()=7,296,062
```

These numbers are statistically plausible and seem to indicate the filter works correctly (the trailing `=` makes python print both the expression and its value, `:,` makes the value be formatted with commans between 1000-steps).

**Is there a reason the show/display/collect methods would produce faulty data?**

Resetting the notebook state and running all cells in sequence and restarting the cluster have not changed the results. I also tried different browsers (edge and chrome).

Technical Details:
DB runtime: 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12) using photon and spot instances
Worker: Standard_DS3_v2 (min 2, max 8 workers)

Comment: i think lazy eval is to blame here. you could check the optimized plan for some hints as well

Comment: Yes! Forcing the execution of the UDF earlier with the `.cache()` method fixed the issue. Thanks for the hint! Although I thing the underlying issue was the non-deterministic UDF and it's probably the cleaner fix.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake was not marking the udf to generate the random timestamps as *nondeterministic*.

Changing the udf definition:

`dtf = F.udf(create_random_datetime, TimestampType()).asNondeterministic()`

makes subsequent filters and display/show/collect statements work correctly.

### Why?

My guess is that not marking the function as non-deterministic allows spark to apply shortcuts for optimization. In this case looking at the first date that is produced by the udf and proceeding with the expectation that the same value will be returned for the other calls. In that case the filters might be applied to the *expected* values, not the actual values.